# Update a value based on Join FlaskSqlALchemy

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables in db.

```
class Vehicle(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "vehicles"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    num_plate = db.Column(db.String(7), nullable=False, unique=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    suspicious = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Vehicle(number playe={self.num_plate}, type={self.type}, suspicious={self.suspicious})"

class Registered(db.Model):
    """
    Registered User
    """

    __tablename__ = "registered"

    regid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    cnic = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    contactno = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    gender = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    dor = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    doe = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    vehicle_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("vehicles.id"), unique=True, nullable=False
    )
```

Now I want to update a specific person's car num_plate. Let's say person with `regid` 3.

I can get his data.

```
reg_visitor = (
    Registered.query.filter_by(regid=3)
    .join(Vehicle)
    .add_columns(
        Registered.name,
        Registered.cnic,
        Registered.contactno,
        Registered.gender,
        Registered.dor,
        Registered.doe,
        Vehicle.num_plate,
        Vehicle.suspicious,
    )
).first()
```

It is of type

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row'>
```

If I print it's attribute, it gives correct answer.

```
print(reg_visitor.num_plate)
```

output is

```
ANB 127
```

Now If I want to update this attribute, I can not.

```
reg_visitor.num_plate = "ABC1234"
```

ERROR:

```
    reg_visitor.num_plate = "ABC1234"
  File "/home/ahmad/Desktop/FYP/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/row.py", line 219, in __setattr__
    raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

My Flask-SQL Alchemy version is '2.5.1', and SQLAlchemy version is 1.4.29.

I do not want to mess up with my versions, is there any other way to update the attribute based on join?

It works well on single tables though.

```
vehicle = Vehicle.query.filter_by(num_plate="ANB 127").first()
vehicle.num_plate = "ABC123"
db.session.commit()
vehicle = Vehicle.query.filter_by(num_plate="ABC123").first() # works well
print(vehicle)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the result of your query `reg_visitor` is a `sqlalchemy.engine.row.Row`, meaning it does not map to a single class.

When you try to update an attribute in it, SQLAlchemy doesn't know how it could update the tables based on the query.

You need to query the Vehicle directly (like again you've shown) to be able to update.

Comment: Oh, so i get the num plate from 1st query, and update it via 2nd query! How dumb I am to not figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

1. add this column to your **Vehicle** Class

   registers = db.relationship('Registered', backref='vehicles',lazy='dynamic')

read about that in [SqlAlchemy Relationship Docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html)

2. after that you can execute

   reg_visitor=db.session.query(Vehicle).join(Registered,Registered.regid==3).one_or_none()
   reg_visitor.num_plate=2331
   db.session.commit()